# Ассемблер. сравнение адресов

Tags: ассемблер

в программе хотел вывести на экран последовательность в 2 строки в четыре колонки. и понял, что оказывается не знаю, как проводить операции с номером адреса. в итоге получается что с offset'ом что без него, будут браться данные по адресу а не будет сам адрес браться и сравниваться. 
там где:

```
cmp     [dim[si]],40h
```

берутся данные, я почему то думал что будет браться адрес.
Вот полный кодик.

```
        model  small
        stack  256
        .data
arr     db     '1$','2$','3$','4$','5$','6$','7$','8$'  ;последовательность которую хотелось бы вывести на экран как матрицу 
spc     db     20h,'$' ;пробел
nl      dw     0a0dh   ;новая строка с возвратом коретки
        db     '$'     ; знак что бы не выводил больше чем надо. для ah:09
        .code
main:   mov     ax,@data
        mov     ds,ax
        mov     ah,09h
        mov     cx,4   
        mov     si,0 
nword:  lea     dx,dim[si]
        int     21h
        mov     dx,offset spc 
        int     21h
        add     si,2h 
        loop    nword
nline:  lea     dx,nl  ;новая строка
        int     21h
        mov     cx,4   ; установил заново кол-во циклов
        cmp     [dim[si]],40h ; вот тут самое главное. думал что взяв в квадратные скобки, будет оперироваться как адрес  
        ja      fnsh
        jmp     nword
fnsh:   mov     ax,4c00h
        int     21h
        end     main
```

подскажите плиз как правильно сделать.

Comment: А что такое 40h, это случайно не смещение внутри dim ? но тогда si как раз его содержит и можно (и нужно) сравнивать именно его `cmp si, 40h`. хотя это зависит от того, что такое dim и размерности его элемента. А сравнивать dim[si] с чем либо точно не стоит, потому что это адрес самого элемента в памяти, как вы можете быть уверены, что физический адрес ячейки в памяти будет равен именно 40h ? А что до квадратных скобок - так они значат именно "значение по адресу"

Comment: Всё правильно поняли, 40h, это смещение при котором хотелось бы что бы программа выполнило другое действие. и в принципе Вы как раз и дали ответ, это я на самом деле по глупости зачем то записывал в смещение ещё и dim, когда действительно достаточно просто si сравнить, благодарствую :)

Comment: А вообще можно ли как то получить смещение внутри сегмента? то есть в примере выше, spc имеет смещение, и надо это смещение закинуть в регистр, как это сделать?

Comment: Но вы и так это делаете. `lea dx,dim[si]` кладет в dx смещение в памяти dim+si, так же как и `mov dx,offset spc` кладет смещение spc в dx. Оба смещения получаются на самом деле еще на этапе компиляции программы. Ассемблер когда вы пишите имя переменной знает по какому смещению он ее размещал. В случае dim[si] он формирует в инструкции `ds:[0x1111+si]` где 0x1111 это как раз то фиксированное смещение dim которое он заранее знает

Comment: на счёт альтернатив команд "lea.." и "mov dx,offset.." понятно. вот к примеру у меня spc имеет смещение относительно начала сегмента данных +17d, соответственно будет ds:0010 h как именно этот [0010] записать в регистр

Comment: `mov dx,offset spc` как раз помещает в регистр dx значение 10h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно сравнить значение из ячейки массива с `40h`

```
cmp dim[si], 40h
```

Если нужно сравнить индекс массива с `40h`:

```
cmp si, 40h
```

Если нужно сравнить значение адреса `dim[si]` с `40h`:

```
lea dx, dim[si] ; получить значение адреса ячейки памяти dim[si] и положить в регистр dx
cmp dx, 40h
```